# How to implement view that Consume Deep Nested Rest API in Angular

Tags: angularjs, web-services, rest, angular

I have restful web service api that provide these urls.

```
/api/cashSales => 
    { 
      id: 1, 
      title: "cash sale", 
      workOrder: { id, 1 } 
    }

/api/cashSales/1/workOrders => 
    { 
      id: 1, 
      code: "wo", 
      rentalTxn: {id, 1}, 
      saleTxns: [{id: 1}, {id: 2}]
    }

/api/workOrders/1/rentalTxn =>
    { 
      id: 1, 
      code: "rt", 
      asset: { id: 1 } 
    }

/api/workOrders/1/saleTxns =>
    [{ 
       id: 1, 
       code: "st1", 
       asset: { id: 2 } 
     }, {
       id: 2, 
       ...
     }]

/api/asset/1 =>
     {
       id: 1
       name: "Asset1"
     }
```

i have Angular cash sale view (represent 1 cash sale) that consuming for 4 levels of data structure hierarchy (cash sale -> work order -> rentalTxn/saleTxns(array) -> asset). which is kind of complex form with multiple directives and controllers. so the question is, how do i fetch data to supply each sub view. for now i have 4 directives.

```
1. <cash-sale />
2. <work-order/> inside <cash-sale /> 
3. <rental-txn/> inside <work-order/> which also using asset. 
4. <sale-txns /> inside <work-order/> which also using asset.
```

before asking this question i fetched cash sale once with all of the nested properties (which i know its the bad idea, it's gigantic). then i try to split it into little piece of object. but i have the problem. i have to deal with so many more http fetch requests. what should i do? each directive have to know how to fetch it's own data? or `<cash-sale>'s controller` should fetch all data and inject into each directives?

Comment: is this angularjs or angular2?  they **are not** the same framework.

Comment: oh sorry it's angularjs. but i think angular2 may have this problem also even it's call component instead of directive in angularjs